# ASP.NET Web Api not invoking when deployed in server

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to invoke the  **Web-Api** in my C# MVC5 website using the following **jquery script**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('hit invoked');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/HitLog',
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (results) {
            alert('Hit logged successfully');
        },
        failure: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

**It is working fine in localhost** but when my website is deployed in server the script is running and the 'hit invoked' alert is displayed, but the Web-API is not invoked and I don't get any further alerts.

Comment: replace `faillure` with `error` to see what happens

Comment: put a break point at the starting of the controller, before the first action, you could just declare a dummy variable, and in your code, i see only controller name, no action name,  incase you are new to webapi, it needs to be registered at the global page, but if you are using .net core, no need

Comment: have u checked the console for any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you put full path in url: '/api/HitLog' that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please give read privilege to web-api, in local-host you have administrative, so no issue, but website treating many users. you should have to give permission to your application.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the server configuration. It should be .net 4.5 version in web.config..